# Conflict between SVN and Web Application - routing

Tags: php, apache, svn, frameworks, routes

I have installed SVN and use it to maintain access to my repositories via the http protocol (`http://localhost/svn/project_name/` maps to the physical location `/var/www/repos`).

I also have Apache installed for my web application (with a physical location of `/var/www/web_app`). This can be access via `http://localhost/`, rendering a default action (Presenter: Homepage, Action: default - this yields `index.php`).

However, when I want to view the Contact Page (Presenter: Contact, Action: default - yielding `http://localshots/contact`) it says:

> NOT FOUND The requested URL /contact was not found on this server.

The error doesn't look like it is a framework error (bad code for routing in the framework or something similar). It looks like there is a conflict between in `.htaccess` or the apache config.

I'm using a PHP framework (called `Nette`, but I think it's not important what framework is being used: I think the problem lies between the routing and apache configs).

Comment: Can you show us your htaccess and virtual_host config?

Comment: Of course, You want htaccess in root folder of Web Application?

Comment: Yes if this one is the one you use?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DRXnZ.png

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that you have no rewrite rule for the url you are requesting.

2 possibility here, you write a new rule like :

```
RewriteRule ^[/]*contact$ index.php?page=contact [L]
```

The second is to modify the url you want to reech like http://localhost/contact.php, then create a php file a the root of your project.

EDIT :
You can also do it like this :

```
RewriteRule ^[/]*contact$ contact.php [L]
```

So you have a beautiful url and redirect directly to your file